# how to find server name from which your asp.net page is rendering from?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net web application. It is deployed on various servers. Is there any way to find out from which server the web page is rendering or loading from ?

Comment: You could check the web-server logs to see when it served the page.

Answer (score 4):

```
Rendered on <%= System.Environment.MachineName %>
```